# Can't use npn on diferent version of nodejs

Tags: node.js, npm, n

I want to use different versions of node in order to different versions of Angular.

I installed n so I can switch my nodejs version, but when switching to an older version of node, npm gives the following error: Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Here's an example of my console

```
root@ovp-TM1703:/home/ovp/Desktop# node --version
v16.17.0
root@ovp-TM1703:/home/ovp/Desktop# npm --version
8.15.0
```

Then I swich version of node

```
root@ovp-TM1703:/home/ovp/Desktop# node --version
v10.13.0
root@ovp-TM1703:/home/ovp/Desktop# npm --version
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Am I doing something wrong?

I am using Linux Mint 21, It is a fresh install.

From what I am seeing it's like npm is not being installed when installing "new" versions of node

```
root@ovp-TM1703:/home/ovp/Desktop# n
     copying : node/16.17.0
   installed : v16.17.0 (with npm 8.15.0)
root@ovp-TM1703:/home/ovp/Desktop# n
     copying : node/10.13.0
   installed : v10.13.0 (with npm )
```

Comment: How did you "switch version of node" (sic)?

Comment: With the command: n

I have edited first post to include new info

Comment: Is the problem just with very old version of node? e.g. try node 12, 14